# Are Python commands suitable in Vim's visual mode?

Tags: python, vim

I have found the following command in AWK useful in Vim

```
:'<,'>!awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Python may also be useful in Vim.
However, I have not found an useful command in Python for Vim's visual mode.

**Which Python commands do you use in Vim**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to make useful one-liner filters in Python. You need to import `sys` to get `stdin`, and already you're starting to push it. This isn't to say anything bad about Python. My feeling is that Python is optimized for multi-line scripts, while the languages that do well at one-liners (awk, sed, bash, I could name others but would probably be flamed...) tend work less well (IMHO) when writing scripts of any significant complexity.

I do really like Python for writing multi-line scripts that I can invoke from Vim. For example, I've got one Python script that will, when given a signature for a Java constructor, like this:

```
Foo(String name, int size) {
```

will emit a lot of the boilerplate that goes into creating a value class:

```
private final String name;
private final int size;

public String getName() {
  return name;
}

public int getSize() {
  return size;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
  return this == that
      || (that instanceof Foo && equals((Foo) that));
}

public boolean equals(Foo that) {
  return Objects.equal(getName(), that.getName())
      && this.getSize() == that.getSize();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return Objects.hashCode(
      getName(),
      getSize());
}

Foo(String name, int size) {
  this.name = Preconditions.checkNotNull(name);
  this.size = size;
```

I use this from Vim by highlighting the signature and then typing `!jhelper.py`.

I also used to use Python scripts I'd written to reverse characters in lines and to reverse the lines of a file before I found out about `rev` and `tac`.

Answer (score 4):

Python is most useful with vim when used to code vim "macros" (you need a vim compiled with `+python`, but many pre-built ones come that way). [Here](http://www.tummy.com/Community/Presentations/vimpython-20070225/vim.html) is a nice presentation about some of the things you can do with (plenty of examples and snippets!), and [here](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/if_pyth.html) are vim's own reference docs about this feature.

Comment: @ Thank you for the links! --- MJD says that only Lisp can do well source code generation at http://lists.warhead.org.uk/pipermail/iwe/2005-July/000130.html . --- @Alex: Which one is more useful Python with Vim or Lisp with Vim?